# How to get following users content AND your own content in one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a social network; I have a table for users' posts.
The table looks like:

> id  fromuid touid   date    ip  content

fromuid is the user who posted the post, and touid is set to whoever you post to. So if you go on someone's page and make a post, touid is set to your UID. However, if you're home and don't post at any one touid will be set to your UID.

Now here's my problem: I'm trying to get the content of the users you're following. There's a table like so for followers:

> id    follower    following   date

Then, in my post's class, I get all the followers and put them into a predefined array like so:

```
        $getRelatedPostsQuery = new Database(); 
    $getFollowers = $getRelatedPostsQuery->query(array("SELECT * FROM follower WHERE follower = ?", array($this->uid)))->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($getFollowers as $key) {
        $followers[] = $key['following'];
    }
```

This is where I begin to struggle. I have this query here:

```
    $getRelatedPosts = new Database();
    $relatedPostsResult = $getRelatedPosts->query(array("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE fromuid IN ('". implode("', '", $followers) ."') ORDER BY id DESC", array()))->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This works absolutely fine, but the problem is, if for example I follow a user called Jack, and a user I'm not following, say, Jill, posts on Jack's wall, I'll see what Jill posted. I obviously want to only see the content of the users I have followed. How would I best go about doing this? Also, I'm guessing this is probably an over-complicated way of doing this, yes? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with joins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're wanting all the posts from only those people whom you're following, and not posts by other people to those that you're following.

If that's the case, a simple addition to your where clause should do the trick:

```
$relatedPostsResult = $getRelatedPosts->query(array("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE fromuid IN ('". implode("', '", $followers) ."') AND fromuid = touid ORDER BY id DESC", array()))->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This will tell the query to only grab the posts where `fromuid` is the same as `touid` (posts where the person posted on their own "wall").

You also asked if there is a simpler way to do it, and there is if you combine the queries:

```
$getRelatedPosts = new Database();
$relatedPostsResult = $getRelatedPosts->query(
                                              array("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE fromuid IN(SELECT fromuid FROM follower WHERE follower = ?) AND fromuid = touid ORDER BY id DESC",
                                                      array($this->uid))
                                                    )->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Or if you'd rather use a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

```
$getRelatedPosts = new Database();
$relatedPostsResult = $getRelatedPosts->query(
                                              array("SELECT * FROM posts, follower WHERE follower.follower = posts.fromuid AND follower.follower = ? AND follower.fromuid = follower.touid ORDER BY posts.id DESC",
                                                      array($this->uid))
                                                    )->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: You, samsquanch are a saint. Im a little unfamiliar with MySQL, it is evident I should probably get more familiar with it in light of this. Thanks very much for the advise, everything now works beautifully.

Comment: Happy to help. I've also added a slightly cleaner `join` version if you'd like to try that one out.

Comment: Just realized, the top result selects all posts which dont post to anyone. Because isnt:  fromuid = touid going to select all posts that users post at themselfs? (it did work still, but when I got a few more testing accounts online things started getting a little messy, got a few errors. I change it now so I dont have the error anymore. ) Sorry about this, Im finding it all very confusing

Comment: It should only select posts which users post to themselves and the user that does the query is following. Can you give an example of one that's being pulled in erroneously?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE fromuid IN (SELECT fromuid FROM follower WHERE follower = ?) AND fromuid = touid ORDER BY id DESC` is what I used (your second solution) which works great. But when I made a new user who im not following, that users posts show up because im asuming its something to do with the `fromuid = touid` part... Not sure. Thanks!

Comment: What do you get when you just run `SELECT fromuid FROM follower WHERE follower = ?`?

Comment: fromuid isnt a column in follower but I tried follower and it returns a few users that Im following (i think). Thanks again, hope Im not being a pain.

Comment: Ah yes, it should be `SELECT follower FROM follower WHERE follower = ?` for the middle query. If you make that change is it returning what you'd expect?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE fromuid IN (SELECT following FROM follower WHERE follower = ?) AND fromuid = touid ORDER BY id DESC` is what I got in the end. Changed the follower to following because we need the people we are following posts (right?). This works well, I can see all the posts of the people Im following but the only thing is, I still cant see my own posts and I cant see what they have posted on other peoples walls unless I remove the `fromuid = touid` part. We're getting closer!

Comment: Any chance you could make a http://sqlfiddle.com/ so I can get a better idea of what your data looks like?

Comment: Could you also do a few inserts on the left side so that there's data we can work with? :)

Comment: Alright, so, you're wanting all the posts from the people that you're following that post onto their own "walls", and nothing else, right?

Comment: Yeah, I would like it to show what the users your following posts on other peoples walls. For example, if I follow Jeffery, id like to see what he posts on other peoples walls

Comment: So you want to see what Jeffrey posts on his wall as well as others', but not what others post on Jeffrey's?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join and you get it in 1 SQL query

You probably have a *user* table with *id* field
you have a table *posts* with *fromuid* and *touid*

Use a table *follower* to make the link between followers and followed with foreign keys (*follower* and *followed*, corresponding to user.id) :

```
follower, followed, date
```

then you can get all post from people followed by current user with a query like that :

```
select * from posts
join follower on follower.followed = post.fromuid
where follower.follower = $this->id
```